# Erroneous behaviour while updating nested dictionary python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

While working on defaultdict class of collection package in python3.7, I see that new key is generated from the duplicate of last key, instead of initiating dictionary. Is there a way to initiate new element with given dictionary which is `init_dict` in below example code.

Example code to reproduce error:

```
from collections import defaultdict
init_dict = {'buy_qty': 0, 
             'sell_qty': 0}

pnl = defaultdict(lambda: init_dict)
pnl['a']['buy_qty'] += 1
pnl['a']['sell_qty'] += 1
```

Now when I do

```
pnl['b']
```

gives me

```
{'buy_qty': 1, 'sell_qty': 1}
```

I am looking for `pnl['b']` to be initialized with `init_dict`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do `init_dict.copy()` in your `lambda` function.

Comment: Thanks @Asocia, It works. Does it work as pointer to the init_dict.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your copying by reference, not by value. So whatever you do to one dictionary, the other will be affected.

You can check this with the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
print(id(pnl['a']))
print(id(pnl['b']))

print(id(pnl['a']) == id(pnl['b']))
```

Which will give the same memory addresses:

```
1817103232768
1817103232768
True
```

verifying that they are the same objects. You can fix this by assigning a shallow copy of the dictionary using [`dict.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy), as mentioned in the comments:

```
pnl = defaultdict(lambda: init_dict.copy())
```

Or casting `dict()`:

```
pnl = defaultdict(lambda: dict(init_dict))
```

Or using `**` from [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)
:

```
pnl = defaultdict(lambda: {**init_dict})
```

---

Additionally, consider using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting, instead of initializing zero count dictionaries yourself:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

pnl = defaultdict(Counter)

pnl['a']['buy_qty'] += 1
pnl['a']['sell_qty'] += 1

print(pnl)
# defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'a': Counter({'buy_qty': 1, 'sell_qty': 1})})

print(pnl['b']['buy_qty'])
# 0

print(pnl['b']['buy_qty'])
# 0

pnl['b']['buy_qty'] += 1
pnl['b']['sell_qty'] += 1

print(pnl)
# defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'a': Counter({'buy_qty': 1, 'sell_qty': 1}), 'b': Counter({'buy_qty': 1, 'sell_qty': 1})})
```

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so they will work the same as normal dictionaries.